# Executing bash file and receive its output to console

Tags: bash

I created file `test` in `/usr/local/bin` with full permissions and with such content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World!
```

When I execute `test` from home directory I don't get output neither I get exception. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: There was a collision with unix `test` command. Everything works fine since I renamed my file to `test2'. I will delete question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is a poor choice of name for your executable, as it will clash with the core utility `test`/`[`. You should change the name to something else.

If you run `which test`, I expect that you'd see a different path to the one that you were expecting.

Comment: Actually, the `!` seems to be fine outside of quotes as there is nothing following it but would cause problems in other circumstances, so I still think it's a good idea to use single quotes.

Comment: The `!` is not interpreted by the shell except when interactive. Quotes are not mandatory here. Your second explanation is the right one.

Comment: @cadrian yeah fair enough, I removed that part.